# dataTaskWithRequest without internet connection

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I'm doing some tests by sending data with a SOAP WebService, a part of my code where they're an error when I'm trying to send data by turn of the Wifi of my MAC:

```
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(theRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        print("Response Login: \(response)")
        let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        print("Body Login: \(strData)")
        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error Login: " + error!.description)
        }
        let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
        if(self.success == "1"){
            self.successSoap = 1
        }
```

It says that strData is nil. So what I have to do ? It is a normaly error because it's not a test on a real device ? I wan't to send an another successSoap value if they're no internet connection.

Error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Printing description of error:
(NSError?) error = domain: "NSURLErrorDomain" - code: 4294966287 {
  ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you inspect the content of `error` ?

Comment: @tomahh Look my edit please

Answer (score 1):

data is an `Optional` type. When you use `data!`, you say to the compiler *trust me, I know data cannot be `nil` here*.

You want to modify your completion handler to take into account the possibility of an error.

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(theRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
    if let error = error {
       // an error occurred processing the request, deal with the error
    } else if let response = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse, let data = data {
        // check response status code
        if (200..<300) ~= response.statusCode {
            let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data)

            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
        } else {
            // server generated on error
        }
    } else {
       // something went wrong
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say data! is even stronger: It says "I know data could be nil here, but if it is ever nil, then please crash my program".

Comment: I don't know why but I get an error even if the SOAP works: `Printing description of error:
(NSError) error = 0xb029aa58 domain: class name = __NSMallocBlock__ - code: 2054954768 {
  ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
}`

Comment: Even though this sample contains some error checking, it's not sufficient. `error` is only not `nil` if a valid request couldn't be composed or if the request couldn't be send to the server. If there is a response from the server, `error` would be never nil. The minimal checks after getting a response should include the HTTP status code and the expected MIME type. In case of a response where the server signals an error,  `data` is not `nil` and contains an error message. Oftentimes, the content type for error messages is text/html and not what was specified in the Accept header in the request.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper thank you for the note ! I'm so used to alamofire that I forgot to check for response content. I've updated my answer, hopefully now covering most of the error handling.